# I am not convinced that SHA2/3 or AES256 is secure

Tags: encryption, aes, sha-256, security-definition

I have been researching cryptography for the past few weeks to try and make sense of a few things, but is simply not making any sense for me.

- If I encrypt a message, send it to another computer, how will that computer decrypt it? It will need to use the same software or algorithem I used. Hence, if the message was intercepted, all they need is to either use AES or SHA which are known algorithms and voi-la, the message. How is this secure?
- Someone has to develop an algorithm like AES. Which means, the source code is not private and can easily be broken. If I convereted a message or a digital fingerprint to hash code. All I need to do is use the same hash algorithm to reverse engineer it since it will always be the same message. How is this secure?

This is very confusing for me

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_%28cryptography%29 ​ ​

Comment: You should research the basic principles of cryptography first, before you bother yourself with cinvrete algorithms, since you appear to have a lot of misconceptions. Here are a few keywords to look out for: symmetric cipher, (secret) keys, hash algorithms, Kerckhoff's principle. You should easily find all that information even on Wikipedia

Comment: "Someone has to develop an algorithm like AES. Which means, the source code is not private and can easily be broken"  - Every algorithm is developed by someone. Whether the source code of an implementation is public or not is not relevant nor it can be deduced from the premise given.

Comment: Now I'm confused… about your research efforts. The questions you're asking hint at the fact you either have been reading the wrong things, or you've not done any research at all. Can you please clarify what you've been reading? This might also limit the scope of your question (as it's currelty a bit **"too broad"*´*). Otherwise, be prepared for some generalized answers. See, covering security proofs of SHA-2, SHA-3, and AES-256 on their own would take more than a short answer. Chances are, that those proofs would additionally need to be expanded upon to ensure you actually understand them too.

Answer (score 4):

> If I encrypt a message, send it to another computer, how will that computer decrypt it? It will need to use the same software or algorithm I used. Hence, if the message was intercepted, all they need is to either use AES or SHA which are known algorithms and voila, the message. How is this secure?

SHA is a hash algorithm and cannot be used *directly* to encrypt messages; first of all it is not designed for it and second it doesn't take a key as input parameter.

The security of AES depends solely on the knowledge of the key, not on the knowledge of the algorithm. This is called Kerchhoff's principle.

> Someone has to develop an algorithm like AES. Which means, the source code is not private and can easily be broken. If I converted a message or a digital fingerprint to hash code. All I need to do is use the same hash algorithm to reverse engineer it since it will always be the same message. How is this secure?

Not being private doesn't mean that it can be easily broken. If that was the case we would not have IT security in the first place.

If you can reverse a hash algorithm then the algorithm is completely broken; *cryptographically secure* hash functions are designed to be one way.